# math calculation not working?

Tags: c#, math

I have 3 global variables V1 saves V2 * V3, but it is not working right.
I debugged with a break at the math code and V2 and V3 have the right value but V1 has 0.0
can anyone help me on this.

some code :

```
costofAlligor = Alligor * AlligorInput;
```

these 2 lines are from the debug screen

> Alligor   2781.9  float
>   AlligorInput  500.0   float

and the full block of math code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    costofAlligor = Alligor * AlligorInput;
    costofBriochit = Briochit * BriochitInput;
    costofChollonin = Chollonin * CholloninInput;
    costofEspitium = Espitium * EspitiumInput;
    costofHydrobenol = Hydrobenol * HydrobenolInput;
    costofIsopropenetol = Isopropenetol * IsopropenetolInput;
    costofMetachropin = Metachropin * MetachropinInput;
    costofPhlobotil = Phlobotil * PhlobotilInput;
    costofPlasteosine = Plasteosine * PlasteosineInput;
    costofPolynitrocol = Polynitrocol * PolynitrocolInput;
    costofPolynucleit = Polynucleit * PolynucleitInput;
    costofPrilumium = Prilumium * PrilumiumInput;
    costofStatchanol = Statchanol * StatchanolInput;
    costofTitanium = Titanium * TitaniumInput;
    costofVitricyl = Vitricyl * VitricylInput;

    totalCost = costofAlligor + costofBriochit 
        + costofChollonin + costofEspitium 
        + costofHydrobenol + costofIsopropenetol 
        + costofMetachropin + costofPhlobotil 
        + costofPlasteosine + costofPolynitrocol 
        + costofPolynucleit + costofPrilumium 
        + costofStatchanol + costofTitanium 
        + costofVitricyl;
}
```

the whole code of form2 is here : http://pastebin.com/87q29tHp
i thought a link would work better as it is quite long.
i know that alot of the math can be done better or differently but i am learning programming and this is the only way i know how to do it at the moment.

Comment: what is costofalligator defined as?

Comment: Is there a reason why this code is defined as a series of multiplication operations followed by a addition operation instead of one calculation? I would say that your problem is in some other place where you are referencing 'costOfAlligor'

Comment: public float costofAlligor; and the rest of the variables are done the same way

Comment: one other handy tip to debug this is to wrap 'costOfAlligor' in a property implementation and put a break point in the 'set'

Comment: @Glenn yes there is a reason ... I am new to C# and learning so that is the only way i know how to do that at this time

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more of the code there has to be something else going on here

Comment: http://pastebin.com/87q29tHp this is the entire form 2 where the math is done

Comment: People who do negative votes for people who are learning are jerks!, i am giving you a positive one doc - At the end thats what forums are for to ask and learn

Comment: Your problem, I beleive, is based on the fact that all of your TextChange event handlers are performing a "TryParse" using the content of TextBox1, instead of their respective target TextBoxes

Comment: You should consider encapsulating all of this values in a class and exposing a public "Calculate()" method with a "get-only" Total Property

Comment: the text box variables are AlligorInput for example and those are saving correctly .... maybe im not understanding the issue you are pointing out ?

Comment: @Glenn i think i know how i can add all of it to a class but the Calculate() method and get-only is what i dont know could you give a short example?

Comment: Step #1 Simplify the problem to a minimal test-case. I suspect that in doing so the problem, if any, will be made evident :-) If not, then the minimal test case can be used to create a better more focused question.

Comment: well in testing i found that if i input 0 in any on the text boxes the entire math block will not calculate. i need them to be able to * by 0 as some of them will be 0

Comment: Offtopic but since you are new i would recommend you to start using `decimal` for monetary values rather than `float` or `double`

Answer (score 0):

Sample...

```
class Sample1
{
    #region Private member variables ('costOf' and 'Input' data)
    float _Alligor;
    float _Briochit;
    float _Chollonin;
    // ... etc, etc.
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties for costOf and Input data
    public float Alligor { get { return _Alligor; } set { _Alligor = value; } }
    // ... etc. etc.
    #endregion

    public void Calculate()
    {
        costofAlligor = Alligor * AlligorInput;
        costofBriochit = Briochit * BriochitInput;
        costofChollonin = Chollonin * CholloninInput;
        costofEspitium = Espitium * EspitiumInput;
        costofHydrobenol = Hydrobenol * HydrobenolInput;
        costofIsopropenetol = Isopropenetol * IsopropenetolInput;
        costofMetachropin = Metachropin * MetachropinInput;
        costofPhlobotil = Phlobotil * PhlobotilInput;
        costofPlasteosine = Plasteosine * PlasteosineInput;
        costofPolynitrocol = Polynitrocol * PolynitrocolInput;
        costofPolynucleit = Polynucleit * PolynucleitInput;
        costofPrilumium = Prilumium * PrilumiumInput;
        costofStatchanol = Statchanol * StatchanolInput;
        costofTitanium = Titanium * TitaniumInput;
        costofVitricyl = Vitricyl * VitricylInput;

        totalCost = costofAlligor + costofBriochit + costofChollonin + costofEspitium + costofHydrobenol + costofIsopropenetol + costofMetachropin + costofPhlobotil + costofPlasteosine + costofPolynitrocol + costofPolynucleit + costofPrilumium + costofStatchanol + costofTitanium + costofVitricyl;
    }

    double totalCost;
    public double TotalCost { get { return totalCost;  } }
}
```

Comment: thank you glen i will try to implement this. on another note i figured one thing out if any of the inputs = 0 it messes the whole math block up will you solution fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your code with assertions to see what's wrong.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Assert(Alligor > 0.0);
    Debug.Assert(AlligorInput > 0.0);

    costofAlligor = Alligor * AlligorInput;

    Debug.Assert(costofAlligor > 0.0);
    ...
}
```